# Accept outlook meeting invite with HTML body in reply (using exchange webservices)

Tags: vb.net

I've written a service that queries an exchange mailbox using exchange webservices to schedule video conference meetings. the idea of this service is to accept meeting invites, query a SQL database for available dial in details out of a pool of details, it then writes these dial in details as HTML body into the accepted email.

This works great when the email account that the invite was sent from is on the same exchange server.

when however the invite comes from an external participant then the accepted mail body only comes through as plain text.

here is my code (for testing I have made the body very simple)

```
Dim accept As AcceptMeetingInvitationMessage = appoint.CreateAcceptMessage(False)
accept.Body = New MessageBody(BodyType.HTML, "<html><head></head><body><span style=""color:red"">This should be red text</span></body></html>")
accept.Send()
```

this works internally and the text comes out red, externally however it does not.

**UPDATE:**
I might have already found the issue, the global message formatting setting on our exchange server for all external domains was set to follow Outlook client settings.

So since my app isn't using outlook to reply to messages the Exchange server formats it as Rich Text which the external mail client does not understand.

will update again on Monday as we need to restart the Exchange transport service for the change to take.

info found here: https://www.codetwo.com/kb/how-to-configure-exchange-server-2000-2003-to-send-rtf-messages-in-html-format/

and here: http://support.risualblogs.com/blog/2011/02/24/html-mails-sent-via-owa-and-outlook-2011-are-received-as-plain-text-mails-externally/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the answer, changing the rich text formatting did not fix the issue. I then ran a powershell command on exchange to force the format to MimeHTML.

this fixed my problem. I think it was a combination of both settings.

info can be found here:
https://www.codetwo.com/kb/forcing-message-formats-in-exchange-2007-2010/